# Android: Using String resource file to fill a Spinner

Tags: android

I'm trying to fill a Spinner with the values of a array using the string resource file (strings.xml) but don't know why, the Spinner appears with no values.

Java code:

```
String[] measures = new String[]{};
Resources res = getResources();
Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

measures = res.getStringArray(R.array.measures);
List<String> list_measures = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(measures));

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list_measures);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sp1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="days">Days(d)</string>
    <string name="hours">Hours(h)</string>
    <string name="minutes">Minutes(min)</string>
    <string name="seconds">Seconds(s)</string>
 </resources>
```

arrays.xml

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="measures">
        <item>@string/days</item>
        <item>@string/minutes</item>
        <item>@string/seconds</item>
        <item>@string/hours</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I can't see where is the problem for my spinner appears with no values.

Comment: **1** - I'd skip the ArrayList. **2** - Why do you have your arrays.xml pointing to strings.xml? You can directly write the values in arrays.xml. And have localized arrays.xml files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you initialize an `ArrayAdapter` with `string-array` resource.

```
      final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.measures)); //Your resource name

      sp1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); //attaching the spinner to a spinner.
```